# R: re-label facet_wrap title with a character string that contains an equal sign

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60),20,3)) 
data$factor <- c(rep("f1", 4),rep("f2", 4), rep("f3", 4), rep("f4",4),rep("f5", 4))
names(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "factor")
melted <- melt(data)
melted$factor <- factor(melted$factor, 
                        levels=paste0('f', 1:5),
                        labels=c('beta[sigma]^2=1', 'beta[sigma]^2=2', 'beta[sigma]^2=3', 'beta[sigma]^2=4', 'beta[sigma]^2=5'))

p <- ggplot(melted, aes(variable, value)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
  geom_boxplot()
p + facet_wrap(~factor, labeller=label_parsed)
```

[image]

Is there a different way of specifying the equal sign in the plot title so that it doesn't have the parentheses around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to skip the `factor/labels` approach and format the `factor` column with `label_bquote`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
melted %>% 
  mutate(new = readr::parse_number(factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, value)) + 
   stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') +
   geom_boxplot() + 
   facet_wrap(~ new, labeller = label_bquote(beta[sigma]^2==.(new)))
```

-output

[image]

---

If we want to use the OP's option with `label_parsed`, change the `=` to `==` in the `labels`

```
melted$factor <- factor(melted$factor, 
                         levels=paste0('f', 1:5),
                         labels=c('beta[sigma]^2==1', 
                                'beta[sigma]^2==2', 
                                'beta[sigma]^2==3', 
                                'beta[sigma]^2==4', 
                      'beta[sigma]^2==5'))
```

Now, it should work

```
p <- ggplot(melted, aes(variable, value)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + 
   geom_boxplot()
 p +
      facet_wrap(~factor, labeller=label_parsed)
```

-output

[image]